# UI Images / Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

I have two view controllers both with UI background images, one is a title screen and the other is an in-game background screen. How would I get another UI Image(the game's main character)to appear on only the in-game screen and not the title screen?

Comment: I am not sure that i get your question but i think you should use an UIImageView.

Comment: I have tried that and the character does appear but the code that I have for the character isn't connected and I seem to be unable to make an outlet connection to the UIViewController.h file

Answer (score 0):

just drag a imageView to one of the viewcontrollers and add a image to it

Comment: I have tried that and the character does appear but the code that I have for the character isn't connected and I seem to be unable to make an outlet connection to the UIViewController.h file